# About data hazard and forwarding with beq in MIPS?

Tags: assembly, mips, cpu-architecture, mips32, cpu-hazard

Why the first `add` needs forwarding?

```
                    # stage:
add $1, $2, $3      # WB
add $4, $5, $6      # MEM
nop                 # EX
beq $1, $4, target  # ID
```

Since `beq` needs the `$1`, if the first `add` is about to execute WB-stage, isn't that no forwarding needed since `beq` at ID-stage, which is about to read the register file? My book says the second and third instruction before the `beq` will need forwarding to avoid data hazard.

---

**Edit**: I found exactly what I meant on [this link slide page 11](http://courses.cs.vt.edu/cs2506/Spring2013/Notes/L13.BranchPrediction.pdf); another slide that solves my another confusing that the first `add` isn't needed is by *another technique* [special hardware, slide page 58](http://www-inst.eecs.berkeley.edu/~cs150/sp10/Lecture/lec11-pipelining.pdf).

Comment: Note that even with forwarding, a `nop` (or a stall in a later MIPS that detected the hazard) is needed after the 2nd add, because `beq` also needs `$4` *in the ID stage*.  (MIPS branch instructions "execute" in the ID stage, which is why the branch-delay slot is only 1 instruction long, not 2.)

Comment: @PeterCordes: I realized in this morning that I should not always assume that it's a concurrent register-file in the ID stage. Your comment is always helpful for me, thank you so much.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In a synchronous digital system, during a cycle, there are two different phases.
During the first phase, operands are read and transformed by means of operators. During the second phase, the resulting data are written to registers.
Depending on the implementation,theses phases can correspond to the first and second half period, or to the complete period and the rising edge of the clock.

In either case, the important aspect is that it is possible to read (during the first phase) and to modify (at the end) the same register. This is why is is possible to do actions like

```
pc <= pc+4
```

in a single cycle.

In the problem that you raise, it is exactly what happens.

The action

```
  add $1, $2, $3      # WB
```

will read the pipeline register with the result during first phase and write is to $1 at the end of the cycle. while

```
 beq $1, $4, target  # ID
```

will read $1 and $4 during the first phase and write the result the ppline registers at the end of the cycle. Hence, without forwarding, it will be the previous value of $1 that will be  written.

(edited according to comment below)

All these explainations are true is branch is dealt with standard HW. In that case comparison is done by the ALU at the "EX" stage and PC is updated at the end of this stage.

But this leads to a branch penalty of two cycles. To reduce this penalty, one can add HW to perform the comparison at the ID stage. In that case, if the comparison requires a value been computed (as $1 in your example), a stall will be required.

Comment: But the same problem is said with no data hazard (thus no forwarding needed) in the data hazard section... I understand your answer and it's clear but I still cannot sum up these ideas...

Comment: I just found that the book I read is confusing, it is probably using two different techniques (one is by concurrent hardware, the other is forwarding like your great answer) but without saying it explicitly... , which made me thought that the first `add` my example would not need the forwarding if this kind of special hardware is used.

Comment: I added some comments at the end of my answer. I do not know if the book is confusing, but branching  is a very complex problem. Actually data hazards depends on the actual harware and two different hardware are considered.

Comment: Yes, original MIPS handled branches in the ID stage, as part of reading registers.  This is why MIPS's 1 branch delay slot is sufficient to fully hide the pipeline bubble of a taken branch in a [classic 5-stage RISC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classic_RISC_pipeline#Control_hazards), by resteering the IF stage.  So yes, @ptr_NE, the first `add` also needs forwarding in this case.  Without forwarding the 2nd add would have to have left the WB stage in the cycle before the `beq` could go through the ID stage, so it would take 3 `nop`s instead of the usual two for `add` feeding an `add`.